# Is performance issue when accessing shared files at a time more than 100 users?

Tags: php, server

I have shared files in my server like,

```
sharedfiles (Folder)
file1.php
file2.php
...
...
```

and folders like `sub1,sub2,sub3`. These are sub-domains.

In sub-domain, I include shared files like,

```
<?php
 include('../sharedfiles/file1.php');
?>
```

When accessing all the sub-domains and include the shared files it will be any performance issue?

Thanks

Comment: Nope, the files are only read, so no file locking involved; and if you use an OpCache it won't even touch the files after the first access